# NGINX Controller Upgrade Using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, quay.io, gcr.io

I installed NGINX Controller 2 years ago using Helm 2 in our AKS clusters, and it pulled the image from quay.io at the time:

> quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.27.0

We are now looking to upgrade our NGINX ingress controllers, and in our **new** clusters I see the image repo is gcr.io:

> k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.20.0@sha256:8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3

I ran the following command using Helm 3 to upgrade Kubernetes NGINX Controller to no avail in our **old** cluster with controller from quay.io:
`helm upgrade awesome-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx -f nginx-reuse-values-file.yaml`

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: current release manifest contains removed kubernetes api(s) for this kubernetes version and it is therefore unable to build the kubernetes objects for performing the diff. error from kubernetes: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

The K8s version is **1.20.9**.

The current quay.io NGINX ingress controller manifest shows following version:
`apiVersion: apps/v1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured it out:

https://github.com/helm/helm-mapkubeapis

The Helm **mapkubeapis** plugin for the win. I had to update deprecated APIs as evident in the error message in my original post. Ran Helm upgrade after updating to the latest APIs for my K8s version successfully.